# Debugging jquery errors android browser

Tags: jquery, android, debugging

I've got an application that uses jquery UI tabs and a slider plugin purchased from some author code selling site.

I have a bug that is only happening on android 2.2's default browser.  Any ideas on how to debug?  I can't get it to happen in chrome, ff, ff for android, safari, or mobile safari.  (I don't even bother with IE anymore.)

What is happening is if I load a tab any way other than by clicking the link to it in the UL then the sliders all break.  Is there a resource for known compatibility issues?

The url is http://jgaylor.net/freelance/140979_nathan/new.html#work in case anyone wants to see the use case better.

Comment: May Helps you ... http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/android-browsers-aboutdebug-what-do-those-settings-do

Comment: @Mike That looks wonderful initially.  I will know more once I get home to play with it.

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if I got your question wrong, but what you can do is, use remote debugging via chrome: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/setup/remote-debugging/remote-debugging